# How to send values to change NavBar with React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So I have a NavBar that I am trying to have change based on certain events, the navbar changes as i have it right now but I don't want to render it in every class I have that loads a new page. 
I used to have the NavBar render inside of my App.js so it was on all pages but then I couldn't figure out how to pass values to change the NavBar correctly. I would rather like to avoid having to pass the same variables to every class that loads a new page. How can I solve this?

Here is my NavBar code

```
import React from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


export default function NavBar(props){

    const logged = props.logged;
    const baseTabs = props.baseTabs;
    console.log('log' +logged )
    console.log('base' + baseTabs)


    return (
        <nav>
            <Link style={{color: 'white', textDecoration: 'none'}} to='/'>
                <h3>Aura Flows</h3>
            </Link>

            <ul className='nav-links'>

            {baseTabs && <Link style={{color: 'white', textDecoration: 'none'}} to='/faq'> <li>FAQ</li> </Link> }

            {baseTabs && <Link style={{color: 'white', textDecoration: 'none'}} to='/pricing'> <li>Pricing</li> </Link> }

            {!logged && <Link style={{color: 'white', textDecoration: 'none'}} to='/login'> <li>Login</li> </Link> }

            {!logged && <Link style={{color: 'white', textDecoration: 'none'}} to='/signup'> <li>Sign Up</li> </Link> }

            {logged && <Link style={{color: 'white', textDecoration: 'none'}} to='/logout'> <li>Logout</li> </Link> }

            </ul>

        </nav>
    );
}

NavBar.propTypes = {
    logged: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    baseTabs: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
}
```

One Class that changes Navbar based on values

```
import React, {Component, useState} from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { auth } from "../Components/firebase";
import '../App.css';
import '../css/SignUp.css';
import NavBar from '../Components/NavBar';


function SignUpPage(){
  const [logged, setLogged] = useState(false);
  const [baseTabs, setBaseTabs] = useState(true);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');

  const signup = event =>{
    // Doesnt let fields be cleared allows viewing of json info in console
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Sign Up function");
    console.log(username + password)
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, password).then(cred => {
      // console.log(cred.user)
    })
    setBaseTabs(true);
    // sessionStorage.setItem('logged', true);
    setLogged(true);
  }


  if(logged === true){
        return (<Redirect to='/home'/>)
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <NavBar logged={logged} baseTabs={baseTabs}/>
      <form className='signUpBox' id='signup-form'>
        <h1>Sign Up</h1>
        <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='Username' onChange={ e => {setUsername(e.target.value)}} required/>
        <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password' onChange={ e => {setPassword(e.target.value)}} required/>
        <input type='password' name='confirmPassword' placeholder='Confirm Password' onChange={ e => {setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}} required/>
        <input type='submit' name='' value='Sign Up' onClick={signup}/>
      </form>
    </div>    
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Concept of state management from useContext hook or use redux for state management.

This youtube video solves the same exact problem that you have.

 
please watch this video [link to video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35lXWvCuM8o)

Comment: This works how i want it but I am getting an issue, if the user clicks the refresh page button then, based on the video the last of movies revert to the set list and removes the added movies, how can i keep the values as they change so they cant be reset? I have an array [{value; false}, {value: true}] instead of movie list but i dont want my values to revert on any page refresh

Answer (score 0):

You can use Context API in React if your app is not going to be big and does not require lot of global state management.

If it does need lot of global state management you can go for Redux.

Answer (score 0):

Use state management, here is a library very easy to use.

1. `npm i shared-reducer-hooks`
2. Create a store

```js
// src/redux/appStatus.js
import SharedReducer from 'shared-reducer-hooks';

const initialState = {
  logged: false,
  showBaseTabs: false
};
const [mapState, dispatch] = SharedReducer((state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'login':
      return { ...state, logged: true };
    case 'toggleBaseTabs':
      return { ...state, showBaseTabs: action.showBaseTabs };
    default:
      return state;
  }
});

export const useLogged = mapState((state) => state.logged);
export const useShowBaseTabs = mapState((state) => state.showBaseTabs);

export const loginAction = () => dispatch({ type: 'login' });
export const toggleBaseTabsAction = (showBaseTabs) => dispatch({ type: 'toggleBaseTabs', showBaseTabs });
```

3. Use in `NavBar`

```js
// NavBar
import { useLogged, useShowBaseTabs } from '../redux/appStatus';

export default function NavBar() {
  const logged = useLogged();
  const showBaseTabs = useShowBaseTabs();
  //...
}
```

4. Use in `SignUpPage`

```
// ...
import { useLogged, loginAction, toggleBaseTabsAction } from '../redux/appStatus';


function SignUpPage() {
    //...
    const logged = useLogged();

    const signup = event => {
    // Doesnt let fields be cleared allows viewing of json info in console
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Sign Up function");
    console.log(username + password)
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, password).then(cred => {
      // console.log(cred.user)
      loginAction(true);
      toggleBaseTabsAction(true);
    })
  }

  if (logged) {
    return <Redirect to="/home" />;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <NavBar />
      // ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hope it will be helpful!